# How django auto generate method?

Tags: python, django

I'm just curious the way Django generate automatically method with flexible parameter name like `c = p.choice_set.filter(choice_startswith = 'Just hacking')`
Can you explain basically how could it be done?

This is the code of the example

```
 import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate in greater detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done by analyzing function's keyword arguments splitting them by field name and condition. Making some simplification the proof-of-concept will look like next snippet:

```
def filter(**kwargs):
    for i in kwargs:
        field, condition = i.split('__')
        print field, condition

>>> filter(choice__startswith='prefix-')
choice startswith
```

Then using field name and conditions certain actions are done on real objects.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're talking about the choice_startswith parameter in your
example. Essentially this works by utilizing python's handling of keyword
arguments. It's pretty simple magic to do and I'll show you here.

Essentially you define a method or function with a signature similar to this::

```
def somefunc(*args, **kwargs):
    print args
    print kwargs
```

As you can see here we defined to strange looking arguments. However these
aren't normal arguments. The `*` in front of args means that any non-keyword
arguments will be stored in the variable `args` as a tuple. The `**` in
front of kwargs means that any keyword arguments will be stored in the variable
`kwargs` as a dict.

So if you run this function like this:

```
>>> somefunc('a', 'b', alpha='alpha', beta='beta')
```

You'll get this output:

```
>>> ('a', 'b')
>>> {'alpha': 'alpha', 'beta': 'beta'}
```

You can manipluate args and kwargs as a tuple or a dict respectively. If you
analyze these you can do what django does with the filter method.

Answer (score 0):

The ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor class provides a manager like objectname_set or related_name in related fields

See:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L433